# For a _search query in Elasticsearch, how to get the query execution plan for complexity analysis?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are following an example in the YouTube video [Elasticsearch text analysis and full text search - a quick introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajNfOPeWiAY).

In addition to the video, we are getting interested in the behavior differences between

- the "full text index" and
- the "regular expression".

**Our Question:**

For Elasticsearch, is there something like the [EXPLAIN (query execution plan)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) of traditional SQL databases? We want to analyze the computing complexities on the above two features.

**The test steps:**

```
# Create index
PUT /reviews
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "review": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

# Populate data
POST reviews/_bulk
{ "create": {} }
{ "review": "The denumidifier helps dry my laundry really quickly. It's great looking, efficient, and I use the water from the tank to water my plants. It's quite noisy, though." }
{ "create": {} }
{ "review": "The rabbit is really wonderful! It runs quickly, my children love it, and it sleeps in the laundry pile." }
{ "create": {} }
{ "review": "Full text search is powerful, but I wish it did my laundry." }

# Self-designed Test:
# The full text analyzer keeps the keyword "laundry". So, for an incomplete spelling "laundr", 
# the full text index does not return a match, however, 
# the regular expression ".*laundr.*" still matches.

GET reviews/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "review": "laundry"
    }
  }
}

GET reviews/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "review": "laundr"
    }
  }
}

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-query-notes
GET /reviews/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "review": {
        "value": ".*laundr.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to analyze your queries, both being complementary:

A. Using the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/search-explain.html)

B. Using the [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/search-profile.html)